# Where are they in this battle in Game of Thrones (S07E04)?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S07E04 "The Spoils of War", Toward the end of the episode, some of the Lannister and Tarly soldiers, Jaime, Bronn and Dickon Tarly find themselves in a field -

> - which ends up being a battlefield between them and Daenerys' Dothraki horde, as well as her dragon, Drogon.

[image]

### Where exactly are they?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They are in [Roseroad](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Roseroad)

> The Roseroad is a major highway in the Seven Kingdoms, second in size only to the Kingsroad. It connects the two largest cities in the realm, King's Landing and Oldtown, via Highgarden, the seat of House Tyrell.

Form [heavy.com](https://heavy.com/entertainment/2017/08/game-of-thrones-season-7-episode-4-map-timeline-of-battle-was-there-plothole-spoilers/) :

> The battle itself takes place right outside of King’s Landing, before they crossed the Blackwater Rush.  We know this because Tarly said to Jamie, before Dany attacked:  “All the gold’s safely through the gates of King’s Landing.” Then Tarly spoke about needing to also bring the last of the wagons (carrying grain) over the Blackwater Rush.

Below is the map:

[image]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spoils_of_War_(Game_of_Thrones)) also say the same:

> **On the Roseroad**
>
> .....
>
> As the caravan approaches King's Landing, the Lannisters and Tarlys are attacked by Daenerys, riding Drogon and leading her horde of Dothraki.
>
> .....

So they are on Roseroad near to King's Landing.

Comment: So ... [here](http://imgur.com/a/cL7iX)?

Comment: might be.......

Comment: @GhotiandChips: It seems most likely, as they weren't in a forest, but seemed to be really close to Blackwater Rush (which is the bridge across the water, I assume from this answer).

Comment: [wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Spoils_of_War) claim it's near to Mander river @Flater and [thisisinsider](http://www.thisisinsider.com/game-of-thrones-where-battle-happened-daenerys-burned-food-gold-2017-8) also thinks same

Comment: @AnkitSharma: I yield to people who know more about it than me (I haven't read the books), but it seems a bit weird to call that crossing "the Blackwater Rush". The Mander doesn't even flow towards Blackwater Bay. Your quote from heavy.com also says _"right outside of King’s Landing"_, and I would not consider the crossing at Bitterbridge to be near King's Landing, let alone _right outside_ it.

Comment: I sad "before they crossed the Blackwater Rush" not crossed and the other water source near by before Blackwater Rush is mander for sure.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: Bitterbridge (the crossing of the Mander) is closer to Highgarden than it is to King's Landing. It seems very weird for Randyll and Jaime to consider their journey as good as done. Unless their caravan was _massively_ spread out. This isn't proof that you're wrong, it just feels a bit out of place considering how Randyll and Jaime refer to the journey being almost over with.

Comment: They are on Roseroad, nothing else is confirmed